# How to run java applet

Tags: java, applet

I try to run java applet(I know that it's old but I have to work with applet).

```
package aplecik;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Kulka {
        int r = 50; // promień - atrybuty klasy
        Color c; // kolor kółka - atrybut klasy
        int x;  // współrzędna x - atrybut klasy
        int y;  // współrzędna y - atrybut klasy
    public Kulka(int r, Color c, int x, int y) {
        this.r = r;
        this.c = c;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public Kulka(int r, Dimension d) {
        this.r = r;
        x = r + (int) (Math.random() * (d.width - 2*r));
        y = r + (int) (Math.random() * (d.height - 2*r));
        c = new Color(
                (float) Math.random(), 
                (float) Math.random(), 
                (float) Math.random());
    }

    public void rysuj(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(c);          
        g.fillOval(x-r, y-r, 2*r, 2*r);     
    }
}
```

---

```
package aplecik;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
public class ApletKulka extends Applet {

    Kulka[] tablica; // atrybut - tablica kulek
    @Override
    public void init() {
        int N = 10;     
        String ile = getParameter("ILE_KULEK");
        if(ile != null){
            try{
                N = Integer.parseInt(ile);
            }catch(NumberFormatException ex){               
                System.err.println("Błędna wartość parametru");
            }
        }

        Dimension d = getSize();
        tablica = new Kulka[N]; 
        for(int i = 0; i < tablica.length; i++)
            tablica[i] = new Kulka(30, d);      
    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        for(Kulka k : tablica)
            k.rysuj(g);
    }
}
```

No matter what I do Still have error class not found appletkulka or can't initialized applet.
Any ideas? I'm using IntelliJ.
I have problem with almost all class like this.
Maybe I have bad configuration in IntelliJ.

Comment: Uhm... how are you running it? In a browser or what?

Comment: IntelliJ by default doesn't support applets. Did you install the necessary plugin? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-applet.html

Comment: What kind of a situation requires you to work with applets? It's not "old", it's *obsolete*. Like learning that the earth is flat (even though that's coming back in a big way).

Comment: Did you try run it with `appletviewer` ?

Comment: I'm running applet in intelliJ. Just click RUN. I installed plugin.
The university requires work with applets

Comment: @ncti I'm sorry to hear that. They could just as easily have you working with `Frame` (if you insist on using AWT), or `JFrame` (Swing). Applets just make things a lot harder for the students.

Comment: I can not do anything about it. Unfortunately, I have to work with applets